# How to find method of encryption

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

when using Asp net mvc for user management they create some table on SQL-sever database like AspNetRoles, AspNetUserRoles so they using a method of encryption for id on table, how to insert new role using SQL insert statement

Comment: Not correct behavior to insert by sql, why you want to insert by sql can you explain , we may find better solution for you.

Comment: i know it's not correct way to insert , but i just found way by using Newid() function.

Comment: Noway. you must use it in standard way mentioned in Parvesh Yadav answer.

Answer (score 0):

create ApplicationDbContext object like this:
`private ApplicationDbContext appcontext = new ApplicationDbContext();`

use this code for adding role in table

```
 `IList<IdentityRole> identityRole = new List<IdentityRole>();`

 identityRole.Add(new IdentityRole() { Name = "name of role" });
          foreach (IdentityRole cat in identityRole)
            {
                var roleexists = appcontext.Roles.ToList();

                    appcontext.Roles.Add(cat);                    

                appcontext.SaveChanges();
```

`}`

I hope this may help.

Comment: my question is how to add role using SQL insert  query

Comment: Did you write any code for this. If not than you have to use ADO.Net for this and command is like "Insert into dbo.AspNetRoles (Id, name) values ('@Id','@name')". Please check the field name from database . I hope this may help. But to do in a right way in c# is by identity class object..

Comment: Thanks, i use the identity class object